# Referencing a Struct not using the variable's name

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, type-conversion

Hello I have a swift file that contains arrays of tuples that I reference with my app. For example, my structure looks like:

```
struct workoutDict {
   static var bicepWorkouts = [("Barbell Curl","Bicep",0,"3x10"), ("x","x",3,"x")]
}
```

I have a global variable named `eqID`. For example, `eqID = "bicepWorkouts"`

There is part of my code where I attempt to call this dictionary. Normally I would use: `workoutDict.bicepWorkouts` and this works fine, but I have other workouts such as barbellWorkouts in my dictionary so i let the user select "bicepWorkouts",  "barbellWorkouts" ect based on user input and need to use that to reference my struct.

Right now i have

```
//Call the global variable to get what workout to look for
code = eqID
let ourWorkouts = workoutDict.code
```

which should set `ourWorkouts = workoutDict.bicepWorkouts` when our `eqID` is set to that, but it keeps giving me the error that workoutDict does not contain the code when I use that reference.

I tried researching alternate methods of referencing structs but I couldn't find anything. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create yet another dictionary to store the names:

```
struct workoutDict {

    static var dicts = [ "bicepWorkouts": bicepWorkouts, "barbellWorkouts": barbellWorkouts ]

}
```

Then you can access the sub dictionaries by:

```
workoutDict.dicts[eqlID]
```

Comment: Ah that is very simple, thank you! will accep you in 7 minutes

Comment: Types, such as `enum`s, `class`es, `struct`s should have leading capitalised letter, i.e. `struct Workout` (and naming it `WorkoutDict` is not so good either, because 1) in Swift we do not abbreviate. and 2) That it contains a Dictionary is an implementation details.  )

Comment: @Sajjon Thank you for those tips! i will remember that in the future.